# Probability of having exactly $1$ girl amongst $n$ kids?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I have $n$ kids and I want to determine the probability that I will have at most, $1$ girl. What is the probability of this happening?

We know that:

$$P(\text{at most 1 girl}) = P(\text{no girls}) + P(\text{exactly 1 girl})$$

For $n$ many kids, I know that $P(\text{no girls})=\frac{1}{2^n}$, because every other combination will have at least $1$ girls, however how can I determine $P(\text{exactly 1 girl})$?

Comment: This is a binomial distribution

Comment: We haven't covered that so we are not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is essentially a sneaky use of the binomial.  You have $n$ children $n-1$ boys $Prob=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ plus one girl $Prob=\frac{1}{2}$.  However in the sequence of children the girl could be in any spot so the probability of exactly one girl is $\frac{n}{2^n}$.

Comment: Is there a more general formula for this?

Comment: General formula is based on binomial distribution.